# Destruction of unification problem on application

Tags: unification

Suppose I have a unification problem

`a b = f u`

Where `f` is neutral and `u` is WHNF and `a` is a meta applied by localvars (by that I mean the localvars where the meta has access to) and `b` is an additional argument.
Does it make sense to simplify that into

- `a = f` (hence solving the meta inside `a`)
- and `b = u`?

I conjecture that Agda is doing this (edit: see [answer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1879/32)), but I'm not sure if it's okay (by "okay" I mean the solution is the most general and unique solution). I am worried that there can be other solutions (not `f`) to `a` where you apply `b` to it results in `f u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definitely examples where this is not a most general solution. Pick for instance `a true = x true`, where `a` is anything of the shape `λ b. if b then (x true) else t`, then `a true = x true` and `true = true` both hold, while `a = x` certainly doesn't.

However, even though this is not "okay" in your sense, it is the typical kind of heuristics that systems that do not care about only finding most general unifiers do implement. For instance, in Coq:

```coq
Variable (x : bool -> bool).

Goal Type.
Proof.
  evar (a : bool -> bool).
  pose proof (eq_refl : (a true = x true)).
  (* This is accepted, and ?a gets solved to x *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some investigation, I take back the statement that I said about Agda doing some unification.

I tried the following code and Agda does not solve the constraint. It seems that I did not completely understand what's going on:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality
open import Agda.Builtin.Sigma

Nana = Nat -> Nat
def : (g : Nana) (x : Nat) -> Σ Nat (λ n -> Σ Nana (λ f -> f n ≡ g x))
def g x = _ , _ , refl
```

The above code was rejected with:

```
_fst_13 : Nat  [ at 7,11-12 ]
_fst_14 : Nana  [ at 7,15-16 ]

———— Errors ————————————————————————————————————————————————
Failed to solve the following constraints:
  _fst_14 _fst_13 = g x : Nat (blocked on _fst_14)
```

So, probably no.